# insert into LINKED POSTGRES from MSSQL causes 'positioned_load in pos_newload failed'

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc, postgis, linked-server

I'm trying to make a sync between MSSQL database with PostGIS. There are in MSSQL views with coords, projection and other data I need. I'm trying to insert into PostGIS view and to create geometry and transform data in view's rule.

I created all needed stuff, but when inserting from MSSQL (same for `using insert into linked server` or `insert into openquery`) it throws me the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PG_SYNC_TEST" returned message "positioned_load in pos_newload failed".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PG_SYNC_TEST" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

Does anyone knows what is happening and what is set up wrong?

Also, MSSQL is 2016 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

**UPDATE** - Linked server definition

> /****** Object:  LinkedServer [PG_SYNC_TEST]    Script Date: 4/28/2017
>   8:06:39 AM ******/ EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server =
>   N'PG_SYNC_TEST', @srvproduct=N'PostgreSQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL',
>   @datasrc=N'pg_sync_test'  /* For security reasons the linked server
>   remote logins password is changed with ######## */ EXEC
>   master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
>   @rmtsrvname=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'mssql_user',@rmtpassword='########'
>
> GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true' GO
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PG_SYNC_TEST',
>   @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true' GO

Datasource (ODBC x64)
[image: datasource (ODBC x64)]

**UPDATE 2** - Query that returns the error:

```
INSERT INTO PG_SYNC_TEST.sync.[public].v_test_points
(lat, lng, projection, elevation, geochem)
SELECT lat, lng, projection, elevation, geochem
FROM geochem
```

Comment: Please provede full query and definition of linked servers `exec sys.sp_linkedservers`

Comment: @MikhailLobanov Please take a look at the Update.

Comment: Could you also post query that returns error? On which server it's executed?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov Updated again. Both servers are on localhost.

Comment: can you post your tables definition - both `geochem` and `v_test_points`?

Answer (score 1):

Check if any trigger is enabled for `PG_SYNC_TEST.sync` & `[public].v_test_points` - if yes, disable and retry.